# Is there a many-to-one reduction from GapSVP to GapCVP?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

I was wondering if by now any poly-time Karp reduction between GapSVP and GapCVP (exact or approximate) exist. I know of the Cook reduction between these problems, but I couldn't find anything about many-to-one reductions between these problems.